# Cannot build quickfix on MacOS sierra

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I can't build quickfix (https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix) on my MacOs sierra.
After run:

```
./bootstrap
./configure
make
```

It shows multiple errors likes these:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/math.h:693:39: error:
      no member named 'fabsf' in the global namespace; did
      you mean simply 'fabsf'?
abs(float __lcpp_x) _NOEXCEPT {return ::fabsf(__lcpp_x);}
                                      ^~
/usr/include/math.h:430:14: note: 'fabsf' declared here
extern float fabsf(float);
             ^
In file included from FieldConvertors.cpp:36:
In file included from ./double-conversion/fixed-dtoa.cc:28:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/math.h:697:40: error:
      no member named 'fabs' in the global namespace; did
      you mean simply 'fabs'?
abs(double __lcpp_x) _NOEXCEPT {return ::fabs(__lcpp_x);}
                                       ^~
/usr/include/math.h:431:15: note: 'fabs' declared here
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still encounters with the issue: The question was asked by the asker also on GitHub, and the bug is already fixed:

Into `src/C++/FieldConvertors.cpp` add `math.h`

https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/pull/161/commits/f248d10e84498735b13c0f05426c6b4e1f1a2179